# AJAX pagination solution for PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, pagination

Right now I use a pagination system that requires url like

http://mypage.com/index.php?page=1 
http://mypage.com/index.php?page=2 
http://mypage.com/index.php?page=3 
http://mypage.com/index.php?page=4 
etc...

So it uses $_GET method to find out what page the user is on.
I decided to switch most of my website to ajax and came over a problem. When I use Ajax to load new content on a page the url stays the same all the time e.g. http://mypage.com/index.php . Therefore pagination system I use is useless.
I was not able to find efficient AJAX pagination systems, (e.g some where lagy, most required user to scrol to the tiop each time he / she clicked on a next page, because they stayed at the bottom of the page when they clicked next page. etc...)

So I decided to ask you lot if anyone has an efficient pagination solution that works with ajax.

**Example of what needs to be paginated:**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));

//Gather profile information
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
$username = $row["username"];
$id = $row["id"];

$data_display .= '<b>'.Name.'</b> has an id of <span style="color: f0f0f0;">'.$id.'</span>';

}

<!doctype>
<html>
<?php echo "$data_display"; ?> //and I need to paginate this entries
</html>
```

**jQuery that loads new content from different pages into #content div**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewHome(){
    $('#woodheader').load("inc/home_top.php", function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(700)
        });
    $('#content').html('<span class="loader">Loading..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="loaderimg" src="images/ajax_loader.gif"/></span>').load("inc/home.php", function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(700)
        });
}
function viewAbout(){
    $('#woodheader').load("inc/about_top.php", function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(700)
        });
    $('#content').html('<span class="loader">Loading..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="loaderimg" src="images/ajax_loader.gif"/></span>').load("inc/about.php", function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(700)
        });
}
function viewProducts(){
    $('#woodheader').load("inc/products_top.php", function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(700)
        });
     $('#content').html('<span class="loader">Loading..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="loaderimg" src="images/ajax_loader.gif"/></span>').load("inc/products.php", function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(700)
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: looked for solutions on different blogs etc. I found some ajax pagination systems, but they were poor.

Comment: The posted code is your service, right? It would help to see the javascript you're currently using to fetch this to the displayed page.

Comment: added it )) sorry I forgot at the beginning.

Comment: If you need a simple for PHP AJAX Pagination you can find the solution at the following URL: http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/php-ajax-pagination-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagination is not as hard as you can think, you can use jQuery's `load()` function to load content into an element with the page's content.

So for example you have:

```
<div id="page-content"></div>
<a href="#" id="link1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Page 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Page 3</a>

<script>
$.ready(function(){
  var currPage = <?=$pageNumber; ?>; // The page number loaded on page refresh
  $('#link1,#link2,#link3').onclick(function(){
    // Get the first number inside the id
    var pageNum = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

    // Don't load the same page
    if(currPage == pageNum) return;

    // Show loading animation or whatever

    // Load the page using ajax
    $('#page-content').load('pages.php?page='+pageNum, function(){
      // End loading animation
      currPage = pageNum;
    });

    return false; // Important for not scrolling up
  });
});
</script>
```

Regarding the url, you have three options to choose from when a user clicks a page link:

1. Just load the page with no changing of the url
2. Use the HTML5 `history.pushState`(see **[MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)**) if supported and with option 3 as fallback for unsupported browsers
3. Use `#page1`, `#page1` etc. as the href value of the links so that the user knows on what page they are on and parse the value of the url in php:

   ```
   $uri = explode('#page', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $pageNumber = intval($uri[1]);
   ```

Comment: one thing how would I add more links say user gets to page 9 and I wan't to display link to page 10?

Comment: kinda just copy pasted it.. seems to work, although I didnt use any php queries etc just plain text.

Comment: That would require setting on page refresh the number of total pages and then just create a javascript function to update the pagination(list of page numbers).

Just use any PHP pagination script you like and instead of generating it using php generate it using javascript(not that hard) with the `currPage` as page number once a page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a index.php that doesn't load any $data_display initially. 
Internally in javascript I would keep a variable named $page that would initially equals 1.

After load it would make a ajax call to names.php?page=$page and pass the results to a handler that presents it to the user.

Then on the links to "back" and "next" I would put a javascript function that first sets $page to the previous or next number, then calls names.php?page=$page and pass the results to the same handler.

Comment: any chance you could provide reference to code used for this? I'm not good in javascript, most of what I use on my website is from blog posts, plugins etc. ))

Comment: Not really, this is just how I would approach it. I normally don't use external source on this kind of tasks, I write it myself. It might not be as fast to do but I get full control over it.

However, I found this for you, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/paging, could be worth a try.